# php json_decode not working from database (pma)

Tags: php, json, decode

I am trying to use PHP's json_decode function to get data from the database (phpmyadmin)(the type is set to text) and set it on the page This is the code that i got:

```
$belangrijkespecs = $productClass->get('belangrijkeSpecs');
$belangrijkespecs = json_decode($belangrijkespecs);
var_dump($belangrijkespecs);
```

This code outputs

```
NULL
```

And when I echo the $productClass->get('belangrijkeSpecs') it outputs:

```
{"Beeldschermdiagonaal":"10,1 inch (25,7 cm)","Beeldresolutie":"1920 x 1200","Batterijduur":"Tot 12 uur","Gewicht":"525 g","Opslag":"32 GB"}
```

When I passed this in an online JSON decode website than I get the right array (from the website https://3v4l.org/IHKZZ):

```
array (
  'Beeldschermdiagonaal' => '10,1 inch (25,7 cm)',
  'Beeldresolutie' => '1920 x 1200',
  'Batterijduur' => 'Tot 12 uur',
  'Gewicht' => '525 g',
  'Opslag' => '32 GB',
)
```

When i try json_last_error() with this code:

```
switch (json_last_error()) {
                case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
                    echo ' - No errors';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                    echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
                    echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                    echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                    echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
                    echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
                break;
                default:
                    echo ' - Unknown error';
                break;
            }
```

It outputs

```
- Syntax error, malformed JSON
```

And if i just use echo json_last_error() it outputs : 4.

i have already tried :

```
$belangrijkespecs = str_replace("/", "", $belangrijkespecs);
```

and

`$belangrijkespecs = rtrim($belangrijkespecs, "\0");`

and

```
$belangrijkespecs = stripslashes($belangrijkespecs);
```

the output of var_dump $productClass->get('belangrijkeSpecs') :

```
string(240) "{"Beeldschermdiagonaal":"10,1 inch (25,7 cm)","Beeldresolutie":"1920 x 1200","Batterijduur":"Tot 12 uur","Gewicht":"525 g","Opslag":"32 GB"
```

The output of echo addcslashes($belangrijkespecs, '\0..\37!@\177..\377') is:

```
{"\;\Beeldschermdiagonaal"\;\:"\;\1\0,\1 inch (\2\5,\7 cm)"\;,"\;\Beeldresolutie"\;\:"\;\1\9\2\0 x \1\2\0\0"\;,"\;\Batterijduur"\;\:"\;\Tot \1\2 uur"\;,"\;\Gewicht"\;\:"\;\5\2\5 g"\;,"\;\Opslag"\;\:"\;\3\2 \G\B"\;}
```

And when i do 
`$belangrijkespecs = stripslashes($belangrijkespecs);` before json_decode it still dosnt work...

Also tried: 
`$belangrijkespecs = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $belangrijkespecs);`
But it did not work.

The structure of this 'belangrijkeSpecs' = http://prntscr.com/lvnsbh

I have looked on the internet but the answers that were given did not help me.

So my question is:
How can i get a array from the json encoded string 
( $productClass->get('belangrijkeSpecs') )

and I expect an array as a return from the json_decode();

Comment: remove the echo from this line `echo $belangrijkespecs = $productClass->get('belangrijkeSpecs');`

Comment: No did not work. :(

Comment: It is far from clear what your issue is and what you are actually trying to do

Comment: I am trying to get a array from the json formated code.

Comment: So this line returns you a JSON String right ? `$belangrijkespecs = $productClass->get('belangrijkeSpecs');`

Comment: Why are you doing this `$belangrijkespecs = str_replace("/", "", $belangrijkespecs);` I dont see any `/` to replace?

Comment: That is what i saw online so i tried it, maby it was hidden, but it did not work

Comment: And i have edit the question with the json last error, thanks for saying,

Comment: A side note, but if you are using PHP >= 5.5 you can replace that entire `switch` with `echo json_last_error_msg();` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: It is still not clear what your actual problem is

Comment: Since the json string in the question decodes fine - it is most likely that `$productClass->get('belangrijkeSpecs')` is not actually returning what you think it is. `var_dump($belangrijkespecs);` (before attempting to decode it) would confirm. Note that reusing/reassigning variables (`$thing = method($thing);`) makes debugging harder - best avoided.

Comment: your right with vardump it says that therer are 240 chars but there are 140

Comment: it says a lot of \ so i tried to remove than before decoding with stripslashes(), but that dosnt work...

Comment: yes i now did. i have added more details to the question

Comment: So am I right in saying... You are doing an addslashes before storing on the database and now you are trying to remove them when you retrieve that json from the table column

Comment: no, i use json_encode on a array and the output of that i do in the database. I am doing nothing to the output of the json_encode exept storing it in the database. I dont know if it matters but the type is text.

Comment: The output of `var_dump($belangrijkespecs);` is truncated (which is apparent because there is no final quote) - please add the exact output of that command to the question. If that is all you see the value in the db has been truncated (there is no closing `}` - which would directly make the json string invalid). All of the`i have already tried :` content in the question is not actually helpful - please focus on the problem not the hacks to try and guess a solution.

Comment: the var_dump is in the question

Comment: What kind of output do you want? Do you want to use it as an API? So the endpoint should return a JSON array? Or do you want to use the array further down in your code? Please be clear about what you are looking for, and how you _expect_ the result.

Comment: i want a array from the json encoded string

Comment: The about is an object, which you _could_ use as well. But I guess you only want the values from the object, instead of a key/value pair? The `$productClass->get('belangrijkeSpecs');` returns one object. Could you show us the code behind this?

Comment: Currently you only have **one** product, which has multiple 'specificaties'. Perhaps you could provide us an example array in way you want to have it?

Comment: Thanks @Matthijs , because you said that you wanted the code behind this i watched it and i escaped the value and i cannot do that with json_decode. thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Please post an answer to your own question, so people can see how you managed to solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The awnser was that i escaped the string before i did the json_decode. And because i did that there where a lot of backslashes.

Thanks to @Matthijs i found it